# Prevent "ghost" images when drag/drop in d3.js

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, d3.js

Anyone have a good reason why I see ghosting when I drag shapes around a canvas with d3.js? Example screenshot:

[image: ghosting as you drag SVG shapes]

Here is the code (coffeescript, which I find vastly easier to read and write):

```
canvas = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width","100%")
  .attr("height","100%")

# patterns
defs = canvas.append("svg:defs")
for c in ["cream","leaf","cardinal-red","baltic-blue","black","brittany-blue","cardinal-red","fern","graphite","green-grape"]
  defs.append("svg:pattern").attr("id","p-tile-#{c}")
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr("width",72)
    .attr("height",72)
    .append("svg:image")
      .attr("width",72)
      .attr("height",72)
      .attr("xlink:href", "img/sw-#{c}.jpg")

#body
body = canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width","500")
  .attr("height","250")
  .attr("rx",30)
  .attr("ry",30)
  .attr("x",20)
  .attr("y",20)
  .attr("fill","url(#p-tile-fern)")
canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width","50")
  .attr("height","65")
  .attr("rx",25)
  .attr("ry",25)
  .attr("x",460)
  .attr("y",30)
  .attr("fill","#fff")

# left eye
leye = canvas.append("svg:svg")
leye.attr("x",100).attr("y",30)
g = leye.append("svg:g")

g.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx",50)
      .attr("cy",50)
      .attr("r",50)
      .attr("fill","url(#p-tile-cream)")
g.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx",30)
        .attr("cy",75)
        .attr("r",10)
        .attr("fill","url(#p-tile-cardinal-red)")

leye.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragstart", ->
    @.__o = [@x.baseVal.value,@y.baseVal.value]
    )
  .on("drag", () ->
    @.x.baseVal.value += d3.event.dx
    @.y.baseVal.value += d3.event.dy
  )
  .on("dragend", -> delete @.__o )
)
```

Here is the created JS for the record:

```
(function() {
  var body, c, canvas, defs, g, leye, _i, _len, _ref;
  canvas = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg:svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%");
  defs = canvas.append("svg:defs");
  _ref = ["cream", "leaf", "cardinal-red", "baltic-blue", "black", "brittany-blue", "cardinal-red", "fern", "graphite", "green-grape"];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    c = _ref[_i];
    defs.append("svg:pattern").attr("id", "p-tile-" + c).attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse').attr("width", 72).attr("height", 72).append("svg:image").attr("width", 72).attr("height", 72).attr("xlink:href", "img/sw-" + c + ".jpg");
  }
  body = canvas.append("svg:rect").attr("width", "500").attr("height", "250").attr("rx", 30).attr("ry", 30).attr("x", 20).attr("y", 20).attr("fill", "url(#p-tile-fern)");
  canvas.append("svg:rect").attr("width", "50").attr("height", "65").attr("rx", 25).attr("ry", 25).attr("x", 460).attr("y", 30).attr("fill", "#fff");
  leye = canvas.append("svg:svg");
  leye.attr("x", 100).attr("y", 30);
  g = leye.append("svg:g");
  g.append("svg:circle").attr("cx", 50).attr("cy", 50).attr("r", 50).attr("fill", "url(#p-tile-cream)");
  g.append("svg:circle").attr("cx", 30).attr("cy", 75).attr("r", 10).attr("fill", "url(#p-tile-cardinal-red)");
  leye.call(d3.behavior.drag().on("dragstart", function() {
    return this.__o = [this.x.baseVal.value, this.y.baseVal.value];
  }).on("drag", function() {
    this.x.baseVal.value += d3.event.dx;
    return this.y.baseVal.value += d3.event.dy;
  }).on("dragend", function() {
    return delete this.__o;
  }));
}).call(this);
```

Comment: i would say, its a nice piece of art

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a redraw bug with WebKit's pattern implementation—the dirty region (where the eye was prior to the latest mousemove) is not properly redrawn. You should file a bug against WebKit. In the meantime, you can probably workaround this using HTML and a background-image style rather than using an SVG pattern.

You could also try this.setAttribute("x", …) or d3.select(this).attr("x", …) rather than assigning to this.x.baseVal.value, but it's fairly unlikely that this would fix the redraw bug.

Comment: Possibly, but I tried fills with straight color codes to the same effect. I will try the setAttr() to see if this makes a difference.